# ResponseEntity returns String instead of xml type in spring boot

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I had used spring and weblogic, 
I have a method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/all/{parentId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> getAll(@PathVariable int parentId) {
    StringBuffer returnValue = new StringBuffer("");
    Power power = iPowerService.loadByEntityId(parentId);
    makeTree(power, returnValue);
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(returnValue.toString(), responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Above method makes xml format for a tree and send it as response to client like this:

```
<201 Created,
<item text="primary" id="740167402" im0="Mehvar_V.png"
    im1="Mehvar_V.png" im2="Mehvar_V.png" isVirtual="true">
    <item text="..." im0="leaf.gif" id="t740167402" />
</item>
<item
    text="fff"
    id="740168675" im0="Mehvar_V.png" im1="Mehvar_V.png" im2="Mehvar_V.png"
    isVirtual="true">
    <item text="..." im0="leaf.gif" id="t740168675" />
</item>
<item text="mmmehdi" id="12" im0="Mehvar_V.png" im1="Mehvar_V.png"
    im2="Mehvar_V.png" isVirtual="true">
    <item text="..." im0="leaf.gif" id="t12" />
</item>
<item text="province" id="123" im0="Mehvar_V.png" im1="Mehvar_V.png"
    im2="Mehvar_V.png" isVirtual="true">
    <item text="..." im0="leaf.gif" id="t123" />
</item>
<item text="power" id="1234" im0="Mehvar_V.png" im1="Mehvar_V.png"
    im2="Mehvar_V.png" isVirtual="true">
    <item text="..." im0="leaf.gif" id="t1234" />
</item>
,{Content-Type=[text/html; charset=UTF-8]}>
```

and client converts this response to tree and shows it.
It had worked successfully
When I migrate to spring boot the response of this method is converted to string like this:

```
"<item text="primary" id="740167402" im0="Mehvar_V.png"
    im1="Mehvar_V.png" im2="Mehvar_V.png" isVirtual="true">
    <item text="..." im0="leaf.gif" id="t740167402" />
</item>
<item
    text="fff"
    id="740168675" im0="Mehvar_V.png" im1="Mehvar_V.png" im2="Mehvar_V.png"
    isVirtual="true">
    <item text="..." im0="leaf.gif" id="t740168675" />
</item>
<item text="mmmehdi" id="12" im0="Mehvar_V.png" im1="Mehvar_V.png"
    im2="Mehvar_V.png" isVirtual="true">
    <item text="..." im0="leaf.gif" id="t12" />
</item>
<item text="province" id="123" im0="Mehvar_V.png" im1="Mehvar_V.png"
    im2="Mehvar_V.png" isVirtual="true">
    <item text="..." im0="leaf.gif" id="t123" />
</item>
<item text="power" id="1234" im0="Mehvar_V.png" im1="Mehvar_V.png"
    im2="Mehvar_V.png" isVirtual="true">
    <item text="..." im0="leaf.gif" id="t1234" />
</item>"
```

As you see `""` SURROUND  my output

What and why is happen?
Why my response send string to client.
I want output as same as it worked successfully

Comment: try to add `produces = { "application/xml", "text/xml" }` to your `@RequestMapping`

Answer (score 0):

With the @ResponseBody, you don't have to wrap your response in a new ResponseEntity, you could juste do this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/all/{parentId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public String getAll(@PathVariable int parentId) {
  StringBuffer returnValue = new StringBuffer("");
  ...
  return returnValue.toString()
}
```

or you could juste remove the response body:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/all/{parentId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> getAll(@PathVariable int parentId) {
```